# PHP SESSION, share sessions from main page to a subpage

Tags: php, session

i have different PHP Scripts running in the main page and a subpage(Members Dashboard) is there a better way to fetch the Session from main page without redirections? the problem is what if people directly access the subpage through bookmarks or from google result

Comment: Then use cookies instead of session

Comment: thanks, good to think about, i'll try to see and read about cache